# iOS 9 New Launch Images and Icons Sizes, has anyone found the new sizes for the upcoming devices yet?

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-9-beta3

For iOS 9 has anyone been able to discover what the new launch image and icon sizes will be for the new upcoming iOS devices?

I checked the Human Interface Guidelines but they have not listed anything yet https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

In Xcode 7 I tried adding a new asset catalog in hopes of discovering them but that was without success.

I'm not sure when we found out the sizes for the iOS 8 releases new iPhone 6 and 6+ but I thought we knew them around early August last year. Maybe there are no new icons to be made this year.

Comment: It is very likely that this year's iPhones will have the same screen sizes as last's (e.g., rumoured "iPhone 6s" and "iPhone 6s+" - unless there's some sort of "iPad Pro" on the line...). But even if Apple has softened its stance on the NDA of upcoming **SDKs**, I'm pretty sure they still want to keep the grip on new product secrecy "airtight". Good luck on your quest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are new icons for the iPad Pro and new splash screens as well. For the iPad pro you will now need an App Icon 167x167 and 2 splash screens measuring:

2048 x 2732 (portrait)
2732 x 2048 (landscape)

They just updated the doc at: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html