# ios 9 launch screen is getting launched in portrait mode

Tags: ios, ios9, device-orientation

I am developing the app which supporst landscape and portrait both modes ,my launch screen has landscape orientation before ios 9 it was ok but ios 9 launch screen is getting launched in portrait mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS 9 New Launch Images and Icons Sizes, has anyone found the new sizes for the upcoming devices yet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823655/ios-9-new-launch-images-and-icons-sizes-has-anyone-found-the-new-sizes-for-the)

Answer (score 6):

i had same problem and i solved it finally.

First, remove the key "**Supported interface orientations**" from **info.plist**.

And then add key "**Initial interface orientation**" to info.plist. Set the key value as "**Landscape (right home button)**".

Finally, add   to your appDelegate.mm.

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, that's because you haven't provided the appropriate launch image for landscape orientation. This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32642194/2799410